# How can I theme the color the disabled text form field's label in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, theming

I want to apply a theme in my Flutter app on the disabled text fields' label because the grey color I have right now is quite hard to read.

I'd like to apply it to my entire app, so I'd like to use theming, however, I didn't find any solution that would enable my to customize the label's text style **only if the text form field is disabled**

**How can I theme and set globally the color the disabled text form field's label in Flutter?**

I know how to change the label's text style conditionally, however, I need to remember to always use the same style (or I could wrap the widget, but that sounds also suboptimal). I can customize the label's color via the `decoration` named parameter, like so:

```
TextFormField(
  enabled: isEnabled,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Value',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: isEnabled ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
  ),
  // .... other fields, like controller might come here
),
```

Answer (score 17):

You could use [Theme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) to wrap around your widget set the property ***disabledColor***.

Example: [Demo](https://codepen.io/vong-panha-huot/pen/WNrxBwb)

```
final customText = Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    disabledColor: Colors.blue,
  ),
  child: TextFormField(
    enabled: false,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        hintText: 'What do people call you?',
        labelText: 'Name *',
    ),
  ),
);
```

or Globally

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      disabledColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
  );
}
```

Comment: This only works if there is no labelColor configured.

Comment: Doesn't work in Flutter 3.13.9

Answer (score 10):

You can use a [InputDecorationTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecorationTheme-class.html) .

MaterialApp has a property `theme` where you can set a custom [ThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html).

ThemeData has a property `inputDecorationTheme`where you can set a [InputDecorationTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecorationTheme-class.html) .

And InputDecorationTheme has a lot of properties that you can use to customize your text fields.

```dart
 MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 22,
              horizontal: 26,
            ),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 35,
              decorationColor: Colors.red,
            ),
        ),
)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I want to change only the disabled text field's label, this changes all.

Comment: Create a custom theme for enable and other disable theme e change it vis setState() whenever you need. @VinceVarga

Comment: Well, thank you, though this is kind of the same approach I added in the question as a workaround.

Comment: Doesn't work in Flutter 3.13.9

Answer (score 4):

To define another label color for disabled fields in `InputDecoration`, you can use `MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith`

```
labelStyle: MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith(
  (Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
      return const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey,
      );
    } else {
      return TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
      );
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: This was the only solution proposed which works without wrapping the TextField with a Theme. Thanks for that.

Comment: Doesn't work when using `initialValue` on `TextFormField` in Flutter 3.13.9.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

style: bodyText().copyWith(color: Colors.black), //bodyText() is defined somewhere else in my case

It forces the text color to be black regardless of whether the TextFormField is enabled or disabled