# Style disabled TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a disabled TextField in Flutter, I want to color the text as if it was enabled.

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  enabled: false,
  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
)
```

[image] Desired

[image] Actual

Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72292112/5882307

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035045/how-can-i-theme-the-color-the-disabled-text-form-fields-label-in-flutter

Comment: Setting disabledColor in ThemeData didn't help, while in the first link I found readOnly option which did what I wanted. Also onTap was useful.
Thanks to the both of you, I had not found these links